How to Bookmark Normal and Decimal Percentage Numbers in Notepad++?
I'm trying to bookmark lines that contain percentage numbers in Notepad++. Specifically, I want to bookmark both whole number percentages (like 9%) and decimal percentages (like 4.5%).
for example I have following list:
VitrtertWW
44.98%
Liertertde
32.52%
Ltettth
Ltertrth9%
Mhrhrththw
4.5%
1992Q2
/////////////////////////

I want to move all percentage numbers to next line.
following regex is working good:
Find: \d+\.\d+%
Replace: \n$0

but my regex have a problem. It just move decimal percentage numbers to next line and normal percentage numbers not move to next line.
how to fix this problem?
I tried following regular expressions too but not working:
(?<!\d)\d%(?!\d)
(|\s)\d%(\s|$)


Make the "dot and digits after" part optional? \d+(\.\d+)?%

@CBroe yes it working - send as answer that i can accept your answer


It just move decimal percentage numbers to next line and normal percentage numbers not move to next line.

That's because your find pattern demands that there is a dot and digits after it. Simply make that part of the pattern optional:
\d+(\.\d+)?%


You could make the decimal part optional:
\d+(?:\.\d+)?%


(?: - start of non-capturing

\.\d+ - the decimal part


) - end of the non-capturing part
? - 0 or 1 matches of the previous match (the non-capturing part)

Demo
